# How to setup a intellij project template with a prompt

Tags: java, intellij-idea, default, minecraft, bukkit

I am looking to setup a project default in IntelliJ idea. However, I'd like it to prompt asking for a project name to name the class and append to the end of the package name. Additionally, I'd like a few other prompts such as version, description, etc. to be put in a certain format in a YAML file. This would be a bukkit plugin project default.

So my question essentially is if I can have the project wizard prompt for things like project name, version, description, etc. and store the information in a YAML file. It would be ideal if the project name was appended on the package, and the main class was renamed to the project name.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but it makes Bukkit & Spigot plugin development with IntelliJ much easier, so i'd like to share it with you anyway:

https://github.com/DemonWav/IntelliJBukkitSupport